# mysql server - how can I restore a backup remotely (from the server itself ) without ssh access ? Hack my server

Tags: mysql, centos, hacking

1. I created an instances on a cloud provider . Generated the .pem key to login through ssh.
2. Installed mysql-server , downloaded the .sql backup on the server.
3. removed the .sql backup from my local computer and by mistake I also deleted the .pem key required to connect to the mysql server through SSH .
   Question : How can I get back the .sql backup file ? I know about mysql dump but I don't know if it works to load a file from the server itself without to be actually logged in through ssh on that server.
   I know it's on /home/back.sql but I can't connect anymore to the server via SSH . Is it possible to get it back or is it lost forever . On the mysql-server I have "root" access but I think the mysql application/server is installed as "mysql" user not "root so I'm not sure if/how can I hack it .
   Centos 6. mysql-server (lasted version through yum ).

Comment: Your best bet would be to email that provider's support and to ask them to help you regain control over your server. I'm sure they always have ways to access their servers.

Comment: can you  login into mysql from remote machine without ssh?

Comment: On EC2 you can move the EBS volume to another server and either access the SQL or change the public key.  Is such a process possible with your hosting provider?

Comment: Why do you want to keep running a server which you don't have access to?

Answer (score 0):

Is the cloud instance EC2? You can log into the IaaS console and create a new public/private key to connect to the instance.

Comment: is not EC2 but even on amazon (ec2) you cannot "attach" a key to an existing instance as far as I know .

Comment: Yes you can, you can add as many ssh keys as you want in the Security Tab in console. What is your IaaS?

Comment: @mako_reactor Yes, you can add SSH keys in the console, **but that does not add them to active instances** in AWS.

Comment: I think no cloud provider allows to attach new keys to existing / active instances due security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so without pem file you can login to your ec2 instance.you have to do the whole exercise from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like

```
create table test (i int primary key auto_increment, a longtext);
load data infile '/home/back.sql' into table test
  fields terminated by '_a_string_which_is_not_in_file_'
   optionally enclosed by '' escaped by ''
  lines terminated by '\n'
  (a);
```

to read your backup file to a table of lines from within mysql, but I think on CentOS your efforts would be blocked by SELinux, as MySQL server isn't supposed to read anything in `/home/`.

So if you can't boot with SELinux disabled (for example with `enforcing=0` boot option) then cloud provider support is your only option.